# Converting Hour from local time to UTC

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a way to convert an hour to UTC time.
the solutions I found are converting Datetime (date + time)
and I need to convert the time only. (HH:MM: SS) without date.

Does C# have a simple way to do this?

Comment: Depending where you are (do you use Daylight Savings?), you need the date part to do an accurate conversion.  Can you show why/how having the Date part causes you problems, and you can't just ignore it?

Comment: A UTCOffset in many timezones depends on the date ...

Comment: @JamesThorpe you right about the cases, my issue is because I need to save the data in 3 separate columns. 1 column is the day (Sunday, Monday, etc) second column is the hour from, the last is hour to. the goal of this table is to choose the time in the week that the customers doesn't want to get alerts from the system. so cant save it as a specific date.

Comment: You cannot do this unless you know exactly what date you are checking and what timezone you are checking. So you would have to check every time you want to raise an alert whether or not the user should be alerted. This isn't something you can do in advance.

Comment: the alert's blocking should huppened in another server that convert the time to the current time (according the customer's GMT ). in the DB I want to save the time as UTC time. @phuzi

Comment: You can't save the time as UTC as it doesn't makes sense unless you also what the date is.

Comment: Sounds like for your design you'll need to store local time and convert it to a full datetime (either UTC or not, depending on use case) on each day, knowing that days date.

Comment: Wait, so it sounds like you are dealing with a _recurring schedule_ rather than specific dates? Is that right? In that case the date will be whatever date it happens to be when you're evaluating whether to send the alert.

Comment: Also don't you want to be going in the opposite direction? You know the UTC time when an alert would be firing, and you want to determine what the local time is for each customer so you know whether to send it, so you want to be converting from UTC to local, no?

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion yes, Im dealing with a recurring schedule So the date has no meaning for me, only the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert like so:

```
    public static DateTime ConvertFromTimeZone(DateTime dateBeingEvaluated, TimeSpan time, TimeZoneInfo zone)
    {
        var dt = new DateTime(dateBeingEvaluated.Year, dateBeingEvaluated.Month, dateBeingEvaluated.Day, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local).Add(time);
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, zone);
    }
```

A couple notes -

If you are completely date agnostic, then you can use January 1 for `dateBeingEvaluated`. This has the advantage that it is not close to any (AFAIK) region's winter/summer time shift, meaning the relative time offsets on that date should be the same for the vast majority of the world for the vast majority of the year. You should therefore get a correct result unless you happen to be checking on a date where one region's DST change is slightly different from another. (For example, UK switched to summer time this past weekend; before that there was a 2 week period where it was only 4 hours ahead of US ET rather than the usual 5). But this sort of discrepancy will be unavoidable if you're discarding the date. I am not one to let the perfect be the enemy of the good, but just be aware that there will be occasional inaccuracies.

---

Based on the comments above, however, it sounds like the OP is dealing with a recurring schedule. In that case the date is indeed known - it's the date that the schedule is being evaluated each day. So if you want to know, for March 27, what is the UTC time corresponding to 9 AM U.S. Eastern Time, use 2023-03-27 as `dateBeingEvaluated` and 9:00 for `time`. That will then return 2023-03-27 14:00Z.

Comment: [_"In the Southern Hemisphere (south of the equator) the participating countries usually start the DST period in September-November and end DST in March-April."_](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/)

Comment: Aha good point @JamesThorpe!!

Comment: @JamesThorpe but aside from inadvertently offending my Aussie friends, it actually doesn't matter that much, since the relative offsets around the world are the same as they are on January 1 for the majority of cases.

Comment: Thank you for the update, its makes sense. but the customer can choose each one of the days of the week (from a list). in this case, what is the best way to deal? for e.g. if I choose Saturday today, the current date won't help me.

Comment: You're looking at this backwards .The way the schedule is entered and stored now is fine. Every time your system generates an alert, you know the UTC datetime. You take that time and convert it to every customer's time zone and then you check the converted time against their schedule to see if they want to get the alert.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using the TimeOnly object? it was introduced in .NET 7

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-7.0

if you don't need timezones etc. this would be the correct approach.